# Omit XML entities when formating

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have a XML file with no right indentation and so much spaces.
There are also entities like LF in this format `&#xA;`

I want to format and reindent the file for readability.
I have tried with xmllint and xmlstarlet but both of them substitute those entities for its ASCII characters so they not longer appear in the formated document.

How can I format my XML without taking into account those entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, for everyone arriving here:

We can use the `tidy` utility. In linux just:

```
sudo apt-get install tidy
tidy -o output.xml --preserve-entities yes -xml input.xml
```

Maybe some options are not meant to be there. Just play around the options to fulfill your requirements.
See the full documentation here:
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html

The most important is `--preserve-entities yes`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't, at least not using a tool that relies on an XML parser.

`&#...;` constructs are not "entities", they're (numeric or hexadecimal) *character references*.  A spec-compliant XML parser converts all character references to their corresponding characters automatically, and this is not a behaviour you can turn off - the application receiving the characters from the XML parser has absolutely no way of knowing whether a given character was a literal or a character reference in the original source.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me that stuff. Although Ive found an utility that can preserve entities like those _numeric character references_

Comment: @JorgeChip my answer is still correct though - the "tidy" tool you're using is not a spec-compliant XML parser, and it isn't designed to be (its job is to clean up possibly malformed XML and HTML, to turn it into something that a compliant parser _can_ handle).

Comment: @ian_roberts Im with you, but it fit the issue very well, just what I need. My XML is supposed to be well-formed and compliant. Just wanted to beautify it ;) Thanks for your answer